# Unable to launch Ubuntu sotware center

Tags: software-center, launcher

I also tried using terminal but geting the error mentioned bellow

```
root@piyush1992-Vostro-2520:/home/piyush-1992# software-center
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 106, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.panes.installedpane import InstalledPane
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/installedpane.py", line 34, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.categories import (CategoriesParser,
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 30, in <module>
    import lxml.etree as ET
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxslt.so.1: symbol xmlBufUse, version LIBXML2_2.9.0 not defined in file libxml2.so.2 with link time reference
```

Comment: You seem to have hit [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1349541). Unfortunately, the workaround there was to completely reinstall Ubuntu. I would try reinstalling `software-center` first by issuing the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center` and try again.

Comment: Indeed. Also you can try using another software centers. Like Appgrid (http://tinyurl.com/n46no42), Lubuntu Software Center (sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center) or use the good old Synaptic to manage your installs. Cheers.